# Grid and Stack based layout with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, templates, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap, underscore.js

Has anyone tried to achieve a Grid, Stack layout in twitter bootstrap in conjunction with Backbone.js Collection ?

[image: Grid to List]

**Demo: ( Without Bootstrap)**

http://vandelaydesign.com/demos/list-grid-view/index.html

List layout was east to achieve with below markup for each model in the collection.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="span12">
 </div>
</div>
```

Grid Layout seems more complicated even when the number of models in a row is set fixed. Assuming I am rendering 4 Models per row here is the required markup

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span3"></div>
  <div class="span3"></div>
  <div class="span3"></div>
  <div class="span3"></div>
</div>
```

Generating the above markup is really hard because i have to wrap `4 div's with class span3` in a `<div class="row">`.

How do i go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the CSS pseudo-class `:nth-child` to achieve this. Here's your HTML:

```
<div class="row column3">
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
    <div class="span3"></div>
</div>
```

The only thing changed is the addition of the `column3` class. Here's the CSS you'll need:

```css
.column3 > div:nth-child(3n+4) {
    clear: left;
}
```

This should tell every the element after every 3rd element to clear to the next line giving you a 3-column layout.